# Support ticket system that integrates with both Salesforce and (FogBugz or Trello or Gitlab)

Tags: help-desk

I'm looking for a ticketing system (like Zendesk) that integrates with both Salesforce and either Fogbugz/Trello/Gitlab. Right now we use FogBugz as a ticketing system but it's not ideal for customer support. We pay for hosted FogBugz so most plugins are out; we currently can't integrate with Salesforce.

We looked at ZenDesk, which does have Salesforce integration, but no Fogbugz support that I can find (at least not without installing plugins, which we can't do).

Any suggestions? Pretend cost isn't an issue. Either hosted or local install is ok.

Sales force integration, and an easy, sensible way to ingrate with either trello, fogbugz or gitlab. We want to be able to spawn certain cases off and then have bidirectional updates between the case and whatever its spawn is. This is so tickets that are bugs with our website can be sent to the developers who won't be using whichever ticketing system we go with.

Comment: Are there any specific features (other than FogBogz/Salesforce integration) that the ticketing system should have?

Comment: @Undo Not particularly. Fogbugz actually works, it's more of the bi-directional integration with other services we're after.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there will not be a tool that does what you want so specifically, but I would

1. Use [BoardThreads](http://boardthreads.com/) as a lean helpdesk on top of Trello;
2. Set up two or three [Zaps](https://zapier.com/zapbook/trello/salesforce/) to create objects in Salesforce when events happen in this same Trello board.